# the demonstration that states that the FT of the ACF function is the square of the DTFT of the signal

Tags: power-spectral-density, autocorrelation

I am following the book The Intuitive Guide to Fourier Analysis & Spectral Estimation with MATLAB. I am trying to selflearn the fourier analysis in matlab.
I got lost in one passage in the demonstration that states that the FT of the ACF function is the square of the DTFT of the signal. I have attached it here[image] As you can see in the passage that I named 1. a delta_tau is missed in my opinion. Can you confirm that? More important in the point 2. in my opinion there should be a tau and not t. So I don't know how it is demonstrated this formula, because if in the passage 2. there is t the demonstration can be ended. I hope you can help me

Comment: I am the author of this book. Thanks for pointing out the typo. Will fix in the kindle version. Thanks to Matt.
Math books are hard to write! Charan Langton

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are right, the derivation is full of typos. The first equation below Eq. $(8.39)$ should read

$$\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}x(t+\tau)e^{\color{red}{-}j\omega\tau}d\tau=X(\omega)e^{j\omega \color{red}{t}}\tag{1}$$

Substituting into $(8.39)$ gives

$$\begin{align}\mathcal{F}\big\{R(\tau)\big\}&=\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}x(t)X(\omega)e^{j\omega t}dt\\&=X(\omega)X(-\omega)=|X(\omega)|^2\end{align}\tag{2}$$

where the last equality is only true for real-valued $x(t)$. However, the overall result is also true for complex-valued $x(t)$ because in that case the ACF is defined differently:

$$\mathcal{F}\big\{R(\tau)\big\}=\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}x^*(t)x(t+\tau)dt\tag{3}$$

Comment: Thank you. I am not an expert so I thought I was missing something

Comment: @AshishBhigah: You're welcome. Many books have typos, especially in their first editions, so be aware ...

Comment: In other book I have seen that the definition of psd has a multiplication (1/2*pi). How can be handled in this demonstration? Does it desappear somehow?

Comment: @AshishBhigah: It's probably best to formulate a new question with the corresponding formula. This makes sure that we understand the problem, and we know which formula you're referring to.